# push an array in to multi dimensional array in php issue

Tags: php, angularjs

I have multidimensional array like this:

```
$comp = [{"d":1},{"v":9}];
```

I need to insert another array

```
$arr = array("s" => 5 );
```

I tried the following code

```
$comp [] = array_push($comp,$arr);
```

I get  the output $comp = [{"d":1},{"v":9},{"s":5},3]
 I dont need 3.
So I have tried

```
$comp [] = json_encode(array_push(json_decode($comp),$arr));
```

But now it shows error.

Plz help me. I am using angular js with php.

Comment: What's the angular part and what is the php part?

Comment: you dont need $comp [] = array_push($comp,$arr); but  array_push($comp,$arr) or see @old_mountains answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `array_push` here. Just assign `$arr` to `$comp[]`

```
$comp[] = $arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you did here, let me explain it to you:

$comp[] - means pushback element.
It works the same way here as array_push($comp,$arr), but that function also  returns the position where that push happened.

So you are pushing result of pushing the element as well as element itself :)

what you need is

```
$comp[] = $arr;
```

OR

```
array_push($comp,$arr);
```